# string as variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of `Objects`: `recs6`, `recs7`, `recs8`...... `recs23`. I want to add a factor in the array using the inner `for` loop. But 'recs+n' is interpreted as string and not as variable name. How can I make it represent the existing variables - `rec6`, `rec7` etc?

```
for(var n=6; n<24; n++){

    for(var m=0; m<'recs+n'.length; m++){
        hourBusyness += parseFloat(('recs'+n)[m].gtse);
    }

    hourAvgbusyness = hourBusyness / ('recs'+n).length;
    console.log(hourAvgbusyness);
}
```

Comment: Don't! Refactor to use a real array instead of a bunch of independent variables with similar names. We have arrays in programming languages for precisely that reason!

Comment: @Quentin - I broke down a big json array by using switch case to make these hourly recs. So recs6 contains all those records which have a date in which hour is 6. Then i would aggregate the gtse and find an average for the 6th hour

Comment: Break it down into an array of arrays, not a bunch of variables (with similar names) containing arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this['recs'+n]` instead of `('recs'+n)`

Comment: You're assuming they're globals.

Comment: … and that the code doesn't need to work in strict mode.

Comment: Yes this is a flawed solution. But this is the answer to the question. The best solution in this case is probably to use an array, if he is in controll of the creation of the variables. But this is not a question about code convention, but about using string as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

"...as an array of Objects..." Without *showing* us that array, we have to guess at what you mean by that.

But if you put those on *an* object as properties:

```
var foo = {
    recs6: {/*...*/}, // Or are these arrays? See note below
    recs7: {/*...*/},
    recs8: {/*...*/},
    recs9: {/*...*/},
    // ...
};
```

Then you can use bracketed notation to access them:

```
for(var m=0; m < foo['recs'+n].length; m++){
```

Or alternately, as dystroy points out in a comment, just use an array:

```
var recs = [
    {/*...*/}, // Or are these arrays? See note below
    {/*...*/},
    {/*...*/},
    {/*...*/},
    // ...
];

for(var m=0; m < recs[n].length; m++){
```

---

Note that you're using the `length` property on them, which suggests that they're arrays, not just plain objects, but the fundamental thing above is how to get the thing (`foo['recs'+n]`).

Comment: Well... An array here would really be cleaner.

Comment: @dystroy: I don't know that we have enough information to know that. Quite possibly, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that. You can, however, put your recs* in a dictionary, so that you can write: `recsDict['recs'+n]` to have access to your nth recs array.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of cheat by using a JSON object.

```
var t = {};
t.recs6 = values;
//later...
t[('recs'+n)]
//can retrieve your data.
```

Comment: There's no JSON here. And why those parenthesis ?

Comment: Please don't confuse JavaScript objects with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin says, this looks like a code-smell to me. Could you try refactoring so that recs is an array of arrays?

However, the following works:

```
window['recs' + n].length
```

Comment: That only works if the variables are globals

Answer (score 0):

You could do create an array where key are recsN, and access it like :

```
var array = [["recs1",5],["recs2",10],...,["recs23", 42]];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
    for(var m=0; m<array[i].length; m++){
        hourBusyness += parseFloat(array[i][m].gtse);
    }
```